# Correct way to do operations on Memmapped arrays

Tags: python, numpy

The operation I'm confused about looks like this. I've been doing this on regular Numpy arrays, but on a memmap I want to be informed about how it all works.

```
arr2 = np.argsort(np.argsort(arr1,axis=0),axis=0) / float(len(arr1)) * 100
#This is basically to calculate Percentile rank of each value wrt the entire column
```

This is what I used on a normal numpy array.

Now. Considering arr1 is *now* a 20GB memmapped array, I have a few questions:

**1:**

```
arr2 = np.argsort(np.argsort(arr1,axis=0),axis=0) / float(len(arr1)) * 100
```

arr2 would be a regular numpy array, I'd assume? So executing this would be disastrous memory wise right?

Considering I've now created `arr2` as a Memmapped array of correct size (filled with all zeroes).

**2:**

```
arr2 = np.argsort(np.argsort(arr1,axis=0),axis=0) / float(len(arr1)) * 100
```

vs

```
arr2[:] = np.argsort(np.argsort(arr1,axis=0),axis=0) / float(len(arr1)) * 100
```

What is the difference?

**3.**

Would it be more memory efficient to separately calculate `np.argsort` as a temporary memmapped array and `np.argsort(np.argsort)` as a temporary memmapped array and then do the operation? Since the argsort array of a 20GB array would itself be pretty huge!

I think these questions will help me get clarified about the inner workings of memmapped arrays in python!

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer part 2 first then 1 and 3.

First, `arr = <something>` is simple variable assignment, whereas `arr[:] = <something>` assigns to the contents of the array. In the code below, after `arr[:] = x`, `arr` still is a memmapped array, whereas after `arr = x`, `arr` is a ndarray.

```
>>> arr = np.memmap('mm', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(1,10000000))
>>> type(arr)
<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>
>>> x = np.ones((1,10000000))
>>> type(x)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> arr[:] = x
>>> type(arr)
<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>
>>> arr = x
>>> type(arr)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

In the case of `np.argsort`, it returns an array of the same type of its argument. 
So in this specific case, I'd think there should be no difference between doing `arr = np.argsort(x)` or `arr[:] = np.argsort(x)`. In your code, `arr2` will be a memmapped array. But there is a difference.

```
>>> arr = np.memmap('mm', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(1,10000000))
>>> x = np.ones((1,10000000))
>>> arr[:] = x
>>> type(np.argsort(x))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(np.argsort(arr))
<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>
```

OK, now what is different. Using `arr[:] = np.argsort(arr)`, if we look at changes to the memmapped file, we see that every change to arr is followed by a change in the file's md5sum.

```
>>> import os
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.memmap('mm', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(1,10000000))
>>> arr[:] = np.zeros((1,10000000))
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
48e9a108a3ec623652e7988af2f88867  mm
0
>>> arr += 1.1
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
b8efebf72a02f9c0b93c0bbcafaf8cb1  mm
0
>>> arr[:] = np.argsort(arr)
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
c3607e7de30240f3e0385b59491ac2ce  mm
0
>>> arr += 1.3
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
1e6af2af114c70790224abe0e0e5f3f0  mm
0
```

We see that `arr` still retains its `_mmap` attribute.

```
>>> arr._mmap
<mmap.mmap object at 0x7f8e0f086198>
```

Now using `arr = np.argsort(x)`, we see that the md5sums stop changing. Even though `arr`'s type is memmapped array, it's a new object and it seems the memory mapping is dropped.

```
>>> import os
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.memmap('mm', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(1,10000000))
>>> arr[:] = np.zeros((1,10000000))
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
48e9a108a3ec623652e7988af2f88867  mm
0
>>> arr += 1.1
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
b8efebf72a02f9c0b93c0bbcafaf8cb1  mm
0
>>> arr = np.argsort(arr)
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
b8efebf72a02f9c0b93c0bbcafaf8cb1  mm
0
>>> arr += 1.3
>>> os.system("md5sum mm")
b8efebf72a02f9c0b93c0bbcafaf8cb1  mm
0
>>> type(arr)
<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>
```

Now the '_mmap' attribute is None.

```
>>> arr._mmap
>>> type(arr._mmap)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Now part 3. It seems pretty easy to lose reference to the memmapped object when doing complex operations. My current understanding is that you'd have to break things down and use `arr[:] = <>` for intermediate results.

Using numpy 1.8.1 and Python 3.4.1

Comment: you have to use the `out` argument where available. Otherwise you always get temporary copies. (of course inplace operators `+=` typically use the out argument)

Comment: @seberg Can you elaborate a bit on this? What is the `out` argument?